# php array_column with unsequential index returns wrong index

Tags: php, arrays, search

So I have an array in php like this:

```
array(
  22 => array()
  23 => array()
  25 => array()
)
```

I am using array_column in search_array to search a column in the sub arrays.

```
$index=array_search('needlehere',array_column(myarray,'columnbeingsearchedhere'))
```

But the array_column is not using the correct indexes, but reindexing them to be 0,1,2...

Is there anyway to keep the correct indexes?

Comment: `array_column` is used to get the common index columns....

Comment: array_combine workaround won't work if some of the subsets in your array don't have the specified column(array_column will dump those instead of return NULL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_column() doesn't maintain indexes (although it allows you to set your own from other data columns in the row), but you can handle that using something like:

```
array_combine(
    array_keys($myarray),
    array_column($myarray,'columnbeingsearchedhere')
);
```

**EDIT**

Alternative, that probably grabs a bit more memory temporarily (unless you don't mind the original array being modified), but might be a bit faster overall (depending on your data):

```
$newArray = $myArray;
array_walk($newArray, function(&$value) use ($columnName) { $value = $value[$columnName]; } );
```

Comment: this is a possible work around but i guess the overhead would be a lot more and might just be worth doing a simple loop through.

Comment: The comment of PixelPaul has to be promoted to answer because doing a loop seems the only meaningful way to address the problem!